# Mongo and Yii -> update with $set a field in all the arrays of a subdocument

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, yii

I'm having problems updating a specific field in all the arrays of a subdocument. I have the following structure in MongoDB:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("539c9e97cac5852a1b880397"),
"DocumentoDesgloseER" : [ 
    {
        "elemento" : "COSTO VENTA",
        "id_rubroer" : "11",
        "id_documento" : "45087",
        "abreviatura" : "CV",
        "orden" : "1",
        "formula" : "Cuenta Contable",
        "tipo_fila" : "1",
        "color" : "#FFD2E9",
        "sucursal" : "D",
        "documentoID" : "0",
        "TOTAL" : "55426.62",
    }, 
    { ... MORE OF THE SAME ... }
],
"id_division" : "2",
"id_empresa" : "9",
"id_sucursal" : "37",
"ejercicio" : "2008",
"lastMonthNumber" : NumberLong(6),
}
```

I need to update the field "documentoID" to a specific value; like "20" for example, in all the arrays of the subdocument "DocumentoDesgloseER". How I can do this?

I tried the following (with $ operator) and is not working:

```
$querySearch = array('id_division'=>'2', 'id_empresa'=>'9', 'id_sucursal'=>'37', 'ejercicio'=>'2008');
$queryUpdate = array('$set'=>array('DocumentoDesgloseER.$.documentoID'=>'20'));
Yii::app()->edmsMongoCollection('DocumentosDesgloseER')->update($querySearch,$queryUpdate);
```

By the way, I'm using Yii Framework to make the connection with Mongo. Any help or advice is welcome.

Thanks ;D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't currently use a positional operator to update all items in an array. There is a ticket opened in the [MongoDB JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) about this issue.

There a two "solutions":

1. Change your schema so that your embedded documents are in the separate collection (it's probably not what you want).
2. The best you can do, if you don't want to change your schema, is to update each subdocument in PHP and then save the whole document.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I didn't know about that I can't use the positional operator for the update. I needed that field to make another change with PHP. I change a little the structure of my program (the PHP part, mongo structure is the same) but I accomplished what I needed. Thanks